# Convert a netcdf time variable to an R date object

Tags: r, date, netcdf, netcdf4, unidata

I have a netcdf file with a timeseries and the time variable has the following typical metadata:

```
    double time(time) ;
            time:standard_name = "time" ;
            time:bounds = "time_bnds" ;
            time:units = "days since 1979-1-1 00:00:00" ;
            time:calendar = "standard" ;
            time:axis = "T" ;
```

Inside R I want to convert the time into an R date object. I achieve this at the moment in a hardwired way by reading the units attribute and splitting the string and using the third entry as my origin (thus assuming the spacing is "days" and the time is 00:00 etc):

```
require("ncdf4")
f1<-nc_open("file.nc")
time<-ncvar_get(f1,"time")
tunits<-ncatt_get(f1,"time",attname="units")
tustr<-strsplit(tunits$value, " ")
dates<-as.Date(time,origin=unlist(tustr)[3])
```

This hardwired solution works for my specific example, but I was hoping that there might be a package in R that nicely handles the UNIDATA netcdf date conventions for time units and convert them safely to an R date object?

Comment: Note that the  newly-proposed and currently in developement awesome `stars` package will handle dates automatically, see the first blog post for an example: http://r-spatial.org/r/2017/11/23/stars1.html

Comment: Ah, I forgot to add that the `units` package seems to handle dates gracefully. Worth a try.

Comment: See my edits in my answer for an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hopes have been met by [package `CFtime`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=CFtime). This package can deal with the CF Metadata Conventions "time" dimension seamlessly, including all defined calendars.

```
f1 <- nc_open("file.nc")
cf <- CFtime(f1$dim$time$units, f1$dim$time$calendar, f1$dim$time$vals)
dates <- CFtimestamp(cf)

# This works reliably only for 3 of the 9 defined calendars
dates <- as.Date(dates)
```

The `CFtimestamp()` function gives a correct output for all possible dates, including the oddball "2023-02-30" but not "2023-03-31" on a "360_day" calendar. Converting to POSIXct is tricky but do you *really* need a `Date` to work with or will a character representation do just fine?

Comment: No idea why on earth this was downvoted. Seems an excellent answer to me! (of course, in the meantime I've migrated from R to python... but anyway ;-)  )

Comment: @ClimateUnboxed Thanks for accepting this and the upvote. And good luck in the world of python!

Comment: @ClimateUnboxed in the end it was probably a wise choice ;)

Comment: I'm not so sure, I still wonder if I should have gone directly to Julia, my aging brain can't face yet another switch in the next years and I've already gone from IDL->metview->NCL->R->python for processing/plotting since my PhD   :-D

Answer (score 5):

***EDIT 2023**: It seems this package/answer is now obsolete, see [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77191110) of Patrick for new way to do this.*

---

I have just discovered (two years after posting the question!) that there is a package called **ncdf.tools** which has the function:

> convertDateNcdf2R

which

> converts a time vector from a netCDF file or a vector of Julian days
> (or seconds, minutes, hours) since a specified origin into a POSIXct R
> vector.

**Usage:**

```
convertDateNcdf2R(time.source, units = "days", origin = as.POSIXct("1800-01-01", 
    tz = "UTC"), time.format = c("%Y-%m-%d", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", 
    "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", "%Y-%m-%d %Z %H:%M", "%Y-%m-%d %Z %H:%M:%S"))
```

**Arguments:**

```
time.source
```

numeric vector or netCDF connection: either a number of time units since origin or a netCDF file connection, In the latter case, the time vector is extracted from the netCDF file, This file, and especially the time variable, has to follow the CF netCDF conventions.

```
units
```

character string: units of the time source. *If the source is a netCDF file, this value is ignored and is read from that file.*

```
origin
```

POSIXct object: Origin or day/hour zero of the time source. *If the source is a netCDF file, this value is ignored and is read from that file.*

Thus it is enough to simply pass the netcdf connection as the first argument and the function handles the rest. **Caveat: This will only work if the netCDF file follows [CF conventions](http://cfconventions.org/)** (e.g. if your units are "years since" instead of "seconds since" or "days since" it will fail for example).

More details on the function are available here:
https://rdrr.io/cran/ncdf.tools/man/convertDateNcdf2R.html

Comment: Package `ncdf.tools` has been archived. Instead there is now a package `CFtime` which fully supports the CF Metadata Conventions "time" dimension.

Answer (score 3):

There is not, that I know of. I have this handy function using `lubridate`, which is basically identical to yours.

```
getNcTime <- function(nc) {
    require(lubridate)
    ncdims <- names(nc$dim) #get netcdf dimensions
    timevar <- ncdims[which(ncdims %in% c("time", "Time", "datetime", "Datetime", "date", "Date"))[1]] #find time variable
    times <- ncvar_get(nc, timevar)
    if (length(timevar)==0) stop("ERROR! Could not identify the correct time variable")
    timeatt <- ncatt_get(nc, timevar) #get attributes
    timedef <- strsplit(timeatt$units, " ")[[1]]
    timeunit <- timedef[1]
    tz <- timedef[5]
    timestart <- strsplit(timedef[4], ":")[[1]]
    if (length(timestart) != 3 || timestart[1] > 24 || timestart[2] > 60 || timestart[3] > 60 || any(timestart < 0)) {
        cat("Warning:", timestart, "not a valid start time. Assuming 00:00:00\n")
        warning(paste("Warning:", timestart, "not a valid start time. Assuming 00:00:00\n"))
        timedef[4] <- "00:00:00"
    }
    if (! tz %in% OlsonNames()) {
        cat("Warning:", tz, "not a valid timezone. Assuming UTC\n")
        warning(paste("Warning:", timestart, "not a valid start time. Assuming 00:00:00\n"))
        tz <- "UTC"
    }
    timestart <- ymd_hms(paste(timedef[3], timedef[4]), tz=tz)
    f <- switch(tolower(timeunit), #Find the correct lubridate time function based on the unit
        seconds=seconds, second=seconds, sec=seconds,
        minutes=minutes, minute=minutes, min=minutes,
        hours=hours,     hour=hours,     h=hours,
        days=days,       day=days,       d=days,
        months=months,   month=months,   m=months,
        years=years,     year=years,     yr=years,
        NA
    )
    suppressWarnings(if (is.na(f)) stop("Could not understand the time unit format"))
    timestart + f(times)
}
```

EDIT: One might also want to take a look at `ncdf4.helpers::nc.get.time.series`

EDIT2: note that the  newly-proposed and currently in developement awesome `stars` package will handle dates automatically, see [the first blog post](http://r-spatial.org/r/2017/11/23/stars1.html) for an example.

EDIT3: another way is to use the `units` package directly, which is what `stars` uses. One could do something like this: (still not handling the calendar correctly, I'm not sure `units` can)

```
getNcTime <- function(nc) { ##NEW VERSION, with the units package
    require(units)
    require(ncdf4)
    options(warn=1) #show warnings by default
    if (is.character(nc)) nc <- nc_open(nc)
    ncdims <- names(nc$dim) #get netcdf dimensions
    timevar <- ncdims[which(ncdims %in% c("time", "Time", "datetime", "Datetime", "date", "Date"))] #find (first) time variable
    if (length(timevar) > 1) {
        warning(paste("Found more than one time var. Using the first:", timevar[1]))
        timevar <- timevar[1]
    }
    if (length(timevar)!=1) stop("ERROR! Could not identify the correct time variable")
    times <- ncvar_get(nc, timevar) #get time data
    timeatt <- ncatt_get(nc, timevar) #get attributes
    timeunit <- timeatt$units
    units(times) <- make_unit(timeunit)
    as.POSIXct(time)
}
```

Comment: NOTE: neither AF7's function or SnowFrog's function can handle the `calendar=365_day`  attribute correctly, while `ncdf4.helpers::nc.get.time.series` works with a 365 day calendar!

Comment: The `units` package is a wrapper around UDUNITS, which does not know about calendars - these are defined in the CF Metadata Conventions. Use package `CFtime` for a one-stop solution.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get @AF7's function to work with my files so I wrote my own. The function below creates a POSIXct vector of dates, for which the start date, time interval, unit and length are read from the nc file. It works with nc files of many (but probably not every...) shapes or forms.

```
 ncdate <- function(nc) {
    ncdims <- names(nc$dim) #Extract dimension names
    timevar <- ncdims[which(ncdims %in% c("time", "Time", "datetime", "Datetime",
                                          "date", "Date"))[1]] # Pick the time dimension
    ntstep <-nc$dim[[timevar]]$len
    tm <- ncvar_get(nc, timevar) # Extract the timestep count
    tunits <- ncatt_get(nc, timevar, "units") # Extract the long name of units
    tspace <- tm[2] - tm[1] # Calculate time period between two timesteps, for the "by" argument 
    tstr <- strsplit(tunits$value, " ") # Extract string components of the time unit
    a<-unlist(tstr[1]) # Isolate the unit .i.e. seconds, hours, days etc.
    uname <- a[which(a %in% c("seconds","hours","days"))[1]] # Check unit
    startd <- as.POSIXct(gsub(paste(uname,'since '),'',tunits$value),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") ## Extract the start / origin date
    tmulti <- 3600 # Declare hourly multiplier for date
    if (uname == "days") tmulti =86400 # Declare daily multiplier for date
    ## Rename "seconds" to "secs" for "by" argument and change the multiplier.
    if (uname == "seconds") {
        uname <- "secs"
        tmulti <- 1 }
    byt <- paste(tspace,uname) # Define the "by" argument
    if (byt == "0.0416666679084301 days") { ## If the unit is "days" but the "by" interval is in hours
    byt= "1 hour"                       ## R won't understand "by < 1" so change by and unit to hour.
    uname = "hours"}
    datev <- seq(from=as.POSIXct(startd+tm[1]*tmulti),by= byt, units=uname,length=ntstep)
}
```

**Edit**

To address the flaw highlighted by @AF7's comment that the above code would only work for regularly spaced files, `datev` could be calculated as

```
 datev <- as.POSIXct(tm*tmulti,origin=startd)
```

Comment: many thanks - I had borrowed some of AF7 code ideas and merged them in my R script.  I wonder if such a functionality could be contributed to the ncdf4 package itself?  It would be great to have something like this built in as standard.

Comment: Note that this only works for regularly-spaced times, which is not necessarily true for all NetCDFs. Why didn't my function work for you? I'll try to make it more general.

Comment: @AdrianTompkins. There used to be a function calculating the date in the package, but there are so many types of netcdfs that it didn't work with all files, so the developer removed it (Thanks to David Pierce for the info). As it will be the same with my function and currently is with AF7's, best to have these functions unofficial and, at least, help other users perhaps customize their own.

Comment: Thanks, that very useful to know

Comment: I asked the `tidync` dev if maybe he could be interested. Here's the github issue, you might want to express your opinions there: https://github.com/hypertidy/tidync/issues/54#issuecomment-331694920